# How do I solve the convergence $\lim_{n \to \infty}(3^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(3^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

I'm fairly sure I can't bring the limit inside the 1/n and I don't think I can use l'Hôpital's rule. I'm pretty sure I'm meant to use the sandwich theorem but I'm not quite sure how to do that in this circumstance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can take the logarithm and apply l’Hospital’s rule to that.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$3= (3^n)^{1/n}\leq (3^n+1)^{1/n}\leq (3^n+3^n)^{1/n}=(2\cdot 3^n)^{1/n}=3\sqrt[n]{2}$$

Thus

$$3\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}(3^n+1)^{1/n}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}3\sqrt[n]{2}=3$$

We conclude the limit is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ln\big(3^n+1\big)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\ln(3^n+1)}{n}$ , one can observe $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{(3^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(3^n+1)}{n}}=e^{\tiny{{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\ln(3^n+1)}{n}}}}}$
Now by L'hopital's rule, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\ln(3^n+1)}{n}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\frac{3^n\cdot\ln(3)}{3^n+1}}{1}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{3^n\cdot\ln(3)}{3^n+1}}=\ln(3)$$
So finally $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\ln(3^n+1)}{n}}=\ln(3)$ and therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{(3^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=e^{\tiny{{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\ln(3^n+1)}{n}}}}}=e^{ln(3)}=3$

P.S. The result was also clear of the fact that $1$ does not have a significant impact on the limit as $n\to\infty$ and hence the result could've been achieved with ignoring the $1$ in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(3^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}3(1+\frac{1}{3^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}3e^{\frac{1}{3^nn}}=3$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the natural logarithm of the limit, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\ln\left(3^n+1\right)$$

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(3^n\right)-\ln\left(3^n+1\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^n+1}\right)=\ln1=0$. Hence we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\ln\left(3^n+1\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\ln\left(3^n+1\right)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\left[\ln\left(3^n\right)-\ln\left(3^n+1\right)\right]$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\left[\ln\left(3^n+1\right)+\ln\left(3^n\right)-\ln\left(3^n+1\right)\right]$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1nn\ln3$$

$$=\ln3$$

Now $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(3^n+1)^{\frac1n}$$

$$=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\ln\left(3^n+1\right)\right)$$

$$=\exp(\ln3)=3$$